# Deploying to Program Files directory

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce, publishing, visual-c#-express-2010

I have developed a C# application and I would like to deploy it to the `C:\Program Files\Company Name\Product` folder.  I am not seeing the "Company Name" folder created on the target machine.

I copy the files from the "published" directory onto a memory stick (thumb drive).  I take the memory stick to a Windows NT machine and double click on `setup.exe`.  The application is installed, as it appears in the *Start Menu".  I have no idea where the actually destination is.  I know it is not in `C:\Program Files\Company Name\Product` folder.

I am using MS Visual C# 2008 Express Edition Version 3.5 SP1.  This product uses a severely restricted *ClickOnce* installer.  Unfortunately, this is what I am given to work with.

How do I tell C# express to deploy my application into the `C:\Program Files\Company Name\Product` folder?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, as I am having a difficult time searching for any information on this issue.

Note:  I am developing on 64-bit Windows 7 platform.

**Edit:**
I have the Title, Company, Product, Copyright, versions and GUID fields filled out on the Assembly Information dialog box.  The company name is two words with a space between.  Does the space cause problems?

Comment: It is somewhat inevitable that you'll discover that the free edition is only worth what you paid for it.  Not a problem as long as your time is free, of course.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot do that using ClickOnce, since its main advantage is that it doesn't require write access to the Program Files folder.

Comment: Ding ding ding! This is the right answer. See the following handy-dandy comparison chart between ClickOnce and the Windows Installer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4.aspx

Comment: In other words, if I want my application deployed to `C:\Program Files`, I need to use Visual Studio or a 3rd party installer?

Comment: @Thomas, indeed. Depending of your requirements, a Visual Studio setup and deployment project might be sufficient.

Comment: @Thomas: That's correct. The design goal of ClickOnce deployment is that it does *not* require the user to have administrative privileges. Installing to `%PROGRAMFILES%` (at least under Win Vista and later) *does* require that. ClickOnce apps are installed in the user's profile folders. Google Chrome is the most famous example. An installer is your only option. If you don't like VS's setup projects, I recommend [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Comment: Although this is the correct answer, it is a depressing one.  -1 to Microsoft's simplified products.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the company name in the assembly info?

To find out where it is, right click on the start menu icon and go to properties. It will tell you where it is.

Edit: I'm dumb. If you want to do an install to Program Files\Comapny Name, use an installer project not click once. Click once is going to keep it where it can track it for versioning.