# Publishing a WPF app in VS 2013 in to Programm Files -- impossible?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

I wonder, isn't there any way to create an installer to  publish a wpf application to **Program Files**? I guess it's called *ClickOnce* but since I've never used it, I can't get along with it.
And I haven't found any options to specify where to publish it or, at least, to choose whether to publish it in the default location or **Program Files**.

Comment: Which version of visual studio do you use?

Comment: @RezaAghaei, 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: You can use [InstallShield Limited Edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020(v=vs.120).aspx). You will find the project template in `Other Project Types` in `Setup and Deployment`

Comment: Any installer tech will install to **Program FIles**.  ClickOnce apps are  installed to <drive>:\Users\<user>\ **AppData\Local**.  Not only are ClickOnce apps not installed in **Program Files**, they are installed by default for _current user_ only

Comment: You can also use [Visual Studio Setup Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx) if you get the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects] extension.(https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify where your application will be installed in clickonce, see this answers :[Deploying to Program Files directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4857546/2363706) [Installation path of ClickOnce apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11208070/2363706)

If you wish to specify where your app will be installed I suggest using [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/).

I also strongly recomed you to read this : [Choosing a Deployment Strategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/e2444w33%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) before you choose your way of installation, a little reading ahead can save a lot of time later.