# Visual Studio Publish Installs Program But I Can't Find the Files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have VS community edition and I can't find my installed files.  I go to the properties window of my start up project and click down to Publish.  My publishing folder location is j:\projectinstall.  My installation folder is \c\program files (x86)\TestProject\    (For some reason, VS doesn't allow destinations such as c:\program files (x86))  I run publish then run the install on another workstation.  Everything works fine -- I get a shortcut on the desktop and I double click it and the file runs.  The problem is that it's like the files don't exist.  I can't find file location, there is no target.  I do a search on my hard drive and the files are just not there.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I tried it with VS 2015 and 2017.

I found the file under c:\users..\appdata\localapps... but I don't want it published into some buried folder.  Please help.

Comment: Is VS running as an administrator?

Comment: What type of application is it ? , I have used installers for normal windows programs with no problems, never have used publish unless it was a website or click once. If it is click once see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857529/deploying-to-program-files-directory)

Comment: It is a windows forms application.  I think the problem has to do with my destination drive but that's just a guess.  I can't find any installers with the Community Edition of VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the VS Community Edition doesn't come with the proper tools to make an installer.  I found a free installer program online: Inno Setup

Comment: No editions of VS come with tools to make an installer, you need to install [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) to be able to do it.

Comment: I tried that extension but I couldn't get it to work for me.  Inno Setup is great.  Super easy and my application doesn't need a super complex install.